# Looking for the same value in two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

=IF((JANUARY!D6=K3),JANUARY!B6,"") 
This is the formula I'm using to try and pull information from the January tab, and place additional information on a different tab. This formula works, however, I need it to look for a specific value in two cells, and not just one.  Basically, what I need the forumala to translate is, if the name Higgenbotham shows up on the January tab, in the cell D6 OR the cell E6,(not both at the same time), then I need the information from cell January tab, cell B6 to show up on the K1 tab in the C6 cell.

Comment: You mean something like: `IF(XOR(JANUARY!D6="Higgenbotham", JANUARY!E6="Higgenbotham"),JANUARY!B6,"")`?

Comment: I believe that’s got it!!  AWESOME!  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Ok.  Used the formula on my ipad version of excel and it worked fine.  However, on my thinkpad, it is giving me a #Name? Error.  I downloaded updates and add ones, but still getting the same error message.  Any ideas?

Comment: Being an old dinosaur who only uses desktops, I'm not sure. Maybe trying to use `Evaluate` (on the `Formulas tab`) to see where the problem is might help?

Comment: Its underlining several things as I click across.  I’ve tried everything, and still getting the same message.

Comment: Is there an alternate way to get the same correct results?

Comment: See the edit in my answer

Comment: FOUND IT!  Instead, I used (JANUARY!D6=“Higgenbotham”)<>(JANUARY!E6=“Higgenbotham”), JANUARY!B6,””)

Answer (score 2):

What's neede is an exclusive or (XOR):

```
=IF(XOR(JANUARY!D6="Higgenbotham", JANUARY!E6="Higgenbotham"),JANUARY!B6,"")
```

A XOR is essentially two `AND`s wrapped in an `OR`

```
=IF(OR(AND(JANUARY!D6="Higgenbotham",JANUARY!E6<>"Higgenbotham"),AND(JANUARY!D6<>"Higgenbotham",JANUARY!E6="Higgenbotham")),JANUARY!B6,"")
```